# How to mint a token on testnet?

Tags: testnet, token, cardano-faucet

Now I am experimenting to mint a token on cardano testnet I have installed the followings like deadalus wallet for testnet and cli tools as well.Then I recived ada from the testnet to the testnet deadalus wallet  Then I have followed thease Instructions over here.

```
cardano-cli address key-gen \
--verification-key-file payment.vkey \
--signing-key-file payment.skey

cardano-cli address build \
--payment-verification-key-file payment.vkey \
--out-file payment.addr \
--mainnet

cat payment.addr
```

From the last command which i have executed given me an ada address when I am pasting that address on deadalus wallet it is showing me the address is invalid. I couldnt find much about this from official documentation as well. What should i do now? Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime you do things on testnet, you need to replace the `--mainnet` flag in your CLI commands with the `--testnet-magic 1097911063` flag. The address you built above is a mainnet address, which is incompatible with testnet.

Comment: Can You give an example script I am seeing this error on my terminal `Invalid option `--testnet'`

Comment: sorry, forgot to include the "magic" option. Edit was applied above ^